# Replace a specific part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

There are plenty of ways to search a string and replace a certain part with something else, but I would like some input on which is the best way to do it.

Take for instance this string :

`http://ashleyfurniture.scene7.com/is/image/AshleyFurniture/B233-48-OPEN-SD?wid=640&hei=180&fit=fit&align=0,0&qlt=95&resMode=sharp2`

Let's say I would like to search for `wid=` and replace what is after until I meet `&` (the first one) or the end of the string if none.

Would I use a regex expression or just a regular search in combination with index of the first `&` after the index of the place where I found what I was searching?

Comment: If you're keen to find the _fastest_ method, [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com) is a great place to experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does sound like a perfect fit for a regex. Regex engines are optimized for finding patterns in a string, and that's exactly what we're aiming to do here. Trying to replicate that in native JavaScript with `search()` etc. is most likely going to be slower. Also, a regex will probably be easier to understand:

```
/\bwid=([^&]*)/
```

will match `wid=` plus whatever follows, until the next `&`, if there is any.

For example,

```
result = subject.replace(/\bwid=([^&]*)/g, "wid=1234");
```

would replace all `wid=<anything>` with `wid=1234`.

**Explanation:**

```
\b     # Start at a word boundary (so we don't match "rowid=" etc.)
wid=   # Match wid=
(      # Match and capture (for later re-use, if necessary):
 [^&]* # Zero or more characters (any character except &)
)      # End of capturing group
```

Comment: Can I also get an argument why regex and not the other ways with `.search()` ?

Comment: @Roland: Sure; I added a line in the first paragraph.

Comment: I see, that sound like a reasonable argument, all I care about is speed as this process might be done on hundreds of subjects.

Comment: Careful! You may have *expected* the regex engine to be faster than a more manual approach; but it isn't. See my answer, and in particular this jsPerf result: http://jsperf.com/replace-a-specific-part-of-a-string

Answer (score 3):

I actually [agree with Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16321233/105570) that a regular expression is the way to go here.

However, **the reason is not performance.** It's code clarity.

The power of regular expressions is their *expressiveness*: how they allow you to express patterns in a clear and concise way. (Of course, they are often horribly abused, hence [the famous quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) implying they are always a bad thing.)

In this particular case, making use of `indexOf` and `substring` ends up being **a lot faster than using a regular expression**:

http://jsperf.com/replace-a-specific-part-of-a-string

As a general rule, writing your own specific logic that's custom-tailored to your problem is almost *always* going to outperform using a more general solution. You shed the baggage of functionality you aren't using; that directly translates to faster performance. (Remember that [making code faster is the same as making it do less](http://philosopherdeveloper.com/posts/best-dependency-is-no-dependency.html).)

In this case, if you did want a semi-general solution to the problem of replacing a portion of a string according to this pattern, you might write a function like this:

```
function replaceBetween(haystack, left, right, replacement) {
  var indexLeft = haystack.indexOf(left);
  var indexRight = haystack.indexOf(right, indexLeft + left.length);
  return haystack.substring(0, indexLeft) + replacement + haystack.substring(indexRight);
}
```

This is relatively readable. However, again, I actually recommend the regular expression approach here because it is clear, and it is almost certainly not a performance bottleneck.

(If you're parsing millions of strings and this actually is a bottleneck, that changes things.)

Comment: +1: Good point, but the comparison isn't entirely fair; my regex contains a word boundary assertion that your JavaScript implementation ignores. So you'd need another check "match `wid=` only if the previous character is not alphanumeric"; that probably won't tilt the result towards the regex solution, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You're right, that is worth mentioning. I skipped that part for brevity... which I'm now realizing was a dumb decision, as including it would've actually reinforced my point about the expressiveness of regular expressions. Maybe I'll add that now.

Answer (score 0):

A regex seems to be your best bet. Assuming the string is in `a`,

```
a.replace(/wid=([^&]+)/,"wid=WHATEVER")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex. this will match all strings which have at least 1 letter and 1 number:

`(?<=[?&]wid=)[^&]*`

## Example

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'http://ashleyfurniture.scene7.com/is/image/AshleyFurniture/B233-48-OPEN-SD?wid=640&hei=180&fit=fit&align=0,0&qlt=95&resMode=sharp2'
Write-Host start with 
write-host $String
Write-Host
Write-Host result string
$String -replace '(?<=[?&]wid=)[^&]*', 'NewValue'
```

## Yields

```
start with
http://ashleyfurniture.scene7.com/is/image/AshleyFurniture/B233-48-OPEN-SD?wid=640&hei=180&fit=fit&align=0,0&qlt=95&resMode=sharp2

result string
http://ashleyfurniture.scene7.com/is/image/AshleyFurniture/B233-48-OPEN-SD?wid=NewValue&hei=180&fit=fit&align=0,0&qlt=95&resMode=sharp2
```

## Summary

By using the `(?<=[?&]wid=)` you are ensured to find the wid key/value set regardless of where it is in the query string.

Comment: As an edge case this solution will prevent accidentally matching keys like "&name-wid=value" if you used the \b word boundary option

Answer (score 0):

You can split the query string after the '?' by '&' in array (key, value) and then edit it and replace whatever you want.

Something like this

```
var url = 'http://ashleyfurniture.scene7.com/is/image/AshleyFurniture/B233-48-OPEN-SD?wid=640&hei=180&fit=fit&align=0,0&qlt=95&resMode=sharp2'
var x = url.split("?");
var query = x[1];
var x2 = query.split("&");
var length = x2.length,
    element = null;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  x3 = x2[i].split('=');
  res[x3[0]] = x3[1]
}
console.log(res['hei'])
```

outputs 180

I think something like this will be faster than regex.